# jQuery Validation Plugin: Validating Checkboxes with Different Names

Tags: jquery, checkbox, validation, jquery-validate

I have a set of 4 checkboxes, all with different names, and require that at least 1 is checked.

I have set the class on all of them to 'require-one'.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="scripts/lib/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#itemForm").validate({

rules: { 
    check1: {  
        required : {  
            depends: function(element) {  
                $('.require-one:checked').size() == 0; 
            }  
        } 
    } 
}
    });
  });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form name="itemForm" id="itemForm" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" id="check1" class="require-one" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="check2" id="check2" class="require-one" value="2" />
<input type="text" class="required" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

If you put in `'return'` before the `$('.require-one:checked').size() == 0;` However, now my problem is the error message will only disappear if Checkbox #1 is selected.  If Checkbox #2 is selected it will not disappear, but will submit.  How do I remove the error if any of the checkboxes are checked?

```
rules: { 
    'nameOfAnyCheckbox': {  
        required : {  
            depends: function(element) {  
              return $('.require-one:checked').size() == 0; 
            }  
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Justin has the correct answer.  Here is an extension that consolidates the error reporting for all the check boxes into a single message:

http://jsfiddle.net/twd8j0tu/

```js
$.validator.addMethod('require-one', function (value) {
              return $('.require-one:checked').size() > 0; }, 'Please check at least one box.');

var checkboxes = $('.require-one');
var checkbox_names = $.map(checkboxes, function(e,i) { return $(e).attr("name")}).join(" ");

$("#itemForm").validate({
    groups: { checks: checkbox_names },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
             if (element.attr("type") == "checkbox")
               error.insertAfter(checkboxes.last());
             else
               error.insertAfter(element);
    }         
});
```

(Please note that this code doesn't seem to work after jquery.validate.js version 1.10.0.  You will have to modify it for later versions).

Comment: Karen, I'm having trouble with this solution, and the JSFiddle seems broken. Submitting the form returns `{"error": "Shell form does not validate...`. That seems to be JSFiddle-generated rather than jQuery-generated.

Comment: @mac9416 The link to the validate.js library was broken in the fiddle, but in the process of fixing it I found out that the code doesn't run as is in validate versions after 1.10.0.   I suspect that the changes required would be minor.

Answer (score 1):

Swatting a fly with a rocket launcher?

```
$('.require-one:checked').size() == 0;
```

Apply the rule on any one of the checkboxes using it's name. For the form to be valid, this checkbox must pass validations. For this checkbox to be valid, at least one of the 4 checkboxes must be checked.

```
$("#itemForm").validate({
rules: { 
    'check1': {  
        required: {
            depends: function(element) {
                return $('.require-one:checked').size() == 0;
            }
        } 
    } 
}
});
```

​

**Updated 2:**

http://jsfiddle.net/MkPtP/1/

Comment: That looks amazing!  I am new to jQuery though.  How would I put that into the jQuery code instead of an onClick event?

Comment: check the jsfiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/zQg8m/. do you have to integrate this with the validation plugin?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, sorry! With the validation plugin.  Do I put it under a Rules heading?

Comment: The code makes sense, but is not working (see my edit above).  It will validate the text box, but not the checkboxes.

Comment: I haven't used jquery validation before, but it has something to do with the use of `depends`. I've removed that and just used a callback function on `required`. Check updated code. link on jsfiddle is updated too.

Comment: btw, the above code looks correct.. pasted the same thing on http://jsfiddle.net/MkPtP/1/ and it works.. i was wrong about not using `depends`

Comment: Yes, it for sure works (but jsfiddle should be '==' not '>'). However, now the error message will only disappear if Checkbox #1 is selected. If Checkbox #2 is selected it will not disappear, but will submit. How do we remove the error class when any of the checkboxes are selected?

Comment: Yeah, doesn't look like a valid solution. I'm trying to figure out the same thing...

Comment: I have to use `length` otherwise I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).size is not a function`. So it looks like this: `$('.require-one:checked').length == 0;`

Answer (score 0):

I think @Anurag was on the right path.  Check out this working version...

http://jsfiddle.net/Y23ec/

Same idea just a different way of doing it.

```
<form name="itemForm" id="itemForm" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" id="check1" class="require-one validate-checkbox-oneormore" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="check2" id="check2" class="require-one validate-checkbox-oneormore" value="2" />
<input type="text" class="required" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $.validator.addMethod('validate-checkbox-oneormore', function (value) {
        return $('.require-one:checked').size() != 0; }, 'need a value');

    jQuery('#itemForm').validate({});
});
```