# jQuery Validation Plugin with metadata on checkboxes?

Tags: jquery, validation, checkbox

I am busy with the validation plugin and i get it not working on my checkboxes and radio inputs. So can somewone help me with this how i can make it work? (i hope it can be done with the metadata just like the input field)

**This is my JS:**

```
$(".valid").validate({
    meta: "validate",
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.insertAfter(element);
    }
});
```

**And the HTML:**

```
<form action="" class="valid">
    <div class="row">
        <label>Name</label>
        <div class="right"><input type="text" value="" name="name" class="{validate:{required:true, messages:{required:'Please enter your name'}}}" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label>Checkboxes</label>
        <div class="right">
            <input type="checkbox" name="family" value="" id="family_one" checked="checked" class="required">
            <label for="family_one">Check on</label>

            <input type="checkbox" name="family" value="" id="family_two" class="required">
            <label for="family_two">Check off</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label></label>
        <div class="right">
            <button type="submit"><span>Click me</span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Form Check HTML checkboxes:**

```
<div class="right">
    <div class="custom-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="family" value="" id="third-check" class="require-one error"><label for="third-check">Check off</label></div>
    <div class="custom-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="family" value="" id="fouth-check" class="require-one"><label for="fouth-check">Check off</label></div>
    <div class="custom-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="family" value="" id="five-check" class="require-one"><label for="five-check" class="">Check off</label></div>
    <div class="custom-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="family" value="" id="six-check" class="require-one">
    <label for="checks" generated="true" class="error">Please check at least one box.</label>
    <label for="six-check">Check off</label></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the latest version of jQuery validate, you just have to add the class "required" to your element tags.

```
<input type="text" class="required" />
```

or

```
<input type="radio" class="required" />
```

That would do for most cases, especially if you won't be requiring a callback function.

Good luck!

EDIT:

Simpy call the validation function by using:

```
$('#idOfForm').validate();
```

Just put an ID on the form so that you can call the function directly.

Cheers!

EDIT 2:

For checkboxes, try:

```
$('#idOfForm').submit(function(e) {
    if($('#family_one').attr('checked') == false) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Please check family one"); //Execute your message here
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, but how you can show the message then? Because when i only add the class then it wont work.

Comment: Also make sure you're using the latest version at http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: Hi, i use the last release. But if you seein my HTML i am use the class required but when i click the button i get only a message fromt he inputfield and not from the checkboxes? So how can i make that work that i see a message?

Comment: mmm oke. But this is not something that can be done with the metadata thing just like the inputfield?

Comment: The reason behind this is beacuse a checkbox is essentially a boolean element. That means it can be either true or false, there are only 2 possible outcomes. To require a checkbox for jQuery validate would also need more work. Try looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445010/jquery-validation-plugin-validating-checkboxes-with-different-names

Comment: Thnx mate... i have got it now. One little question. My error from the checkboxes comes not at the end of the boxes (like the inputfield) but is standing between the last one and the second last one? how can i fix this?

Comment: That's a css question. Depending on how you added your messege, you can either use jQuery append, prepend, after, or before to insert your comment. Or you could just style it via CSS. :)

Comment: I have add the HTML in the first post when i hit the button so you can see what happend. I use a plugin to style the selectboxes maybe thats why? But maybe you know how to fix that? (i think its something to do with error.insertAfter(checkboxes.last()); ?